# Changing menu background color when selected particular menu in sidebar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to change the menu background color when selected sidebar menus in pages? As I created this sidebar menu in different html file (named as sidebar.html) and included that html file in my main page. Here is my code:

**Sidebar.html**

```
<div id="menuwrapper" >
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#"><img src="image/dashboard-icon.png" id="logimg" alt="Smiley face" height="" width=""> 
                <strong style="margin-left: 7px;"> Dashboard</strong>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right" style="padding-left: 113px; font-weight: bold;"></span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#"><img src="image/em_current_openings_icon.png" id="logimg" alt="Smiley face" height="" width=""> 
                <strong style="margin-left: 7px;font-family: sans-serif;">Curent Openings</strong>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right" style="padding-left: 88px; font-weight: bold;"></span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="renumeration.html"> <img src="image/em_remuneration_icon.png"  id="logimg" alt="Smiley face" height="" width=""> 
                <strong style="margin-left: 7px;font-family: sans-serif;">Remuneration</strong>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right" style="padding-left: 103px; font-weight: bold;"></span>
            </a>
        </li>                       
    </ul>
</div>
```

**renumeration.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-include src="'sidebar.html'"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You will need javascript but please show us what you've tried first.

Comment: @Pipo Actually i am not getting how to add javascript for that so i have posted

Comment: Can any one help me this thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think what you meant is simple :hover css pseudo-selector?
Try adding this to page:

```
<style>
li:hover{
    background-color: #ccc;
}
</style>
```

Or there is also a :active selector

Comment: Not on hover need to display the menu as active and background color should be red till i select new menu after selecting another menu the background color should be changed

Answer (score 0):

As you have added jQuery tag into the question, below code should work.

```
$('li').click(function(){
    $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
});
```

But from the code it looks like you are trying to use Angular (I can be wrong here). If yes, don't use jquery solution. Try to solve this requirement using ng-style/ng-class OR write a custom directive for the menu items.